# Why am I getting a NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jtextfield

My name is Russell!

So I am getting these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at PatientPanel.<init>(PatientPanel.java:30)
```

line 30 is this line: `add(fNameField);`

I'm not really sure why. I have never used `JTextField` before though.. so I could be doing something wrong. Heck, I'm new to this whole programming thing. So I could be doing a lot of things wrong! I reviewed other *nullPointerException* cases, but couldn't find one dealing with `JTextField`

I have a feeling it's something very simple, but like I said, I'm new!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class PatientPanel extends JPanel
{

    private JLabel fName = new JLabel("First Name: ");
    private JLabel lName = new JLabel("Last Name: ");
    private JTextField fNameField;
    private JTextField lNameField;


    public PatientPanel()
    {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    add(fName);
    add(fNameField);
    add(lName);
    add(lNameField);
    }
}
```

Comment: `private JTextField lNameField = new JTextField()`. Initialize it before you add it

Comment: Just a note: If you post a question make sure that it easy to read, that will increase the possibility that it will be answered. Format your text so that e.g. error messages are displayed as _blocks_ and don't flow into the text and also highlight things like class names and variables names if they appear in the text. You also don't need to add `Java` to the title, adding it as tag to your question is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for all the tips! Everything is helpful since I really don't know what I'm doing yet--haha

Comment: I don't understand why this question is upvoted? What impressed you? really interesting and weird

Answer (score 2):

```
private JTextField fNameField;
add(fNameField);
```

You never set the value of fNameField before attempting to call a function on it, therefore its value is null and add won't work.
You can probably just use

```
private JTextField fNameField = new JTextField(...);
```

and do the same thing with lNameField

Comment: You, my friend . . .  are amazing.

How do I close this? Like.... if you answered my question-haha. Thank you very much!

Comment: Simply click the checkmark below the vote buttons to the left of the answer